# Generate a sequence of numbers evenly distributed across the given range in R

Tags: r

I need to generate 625 different numbers between 1e-321 and 1e-200. However, when I use seq() function, it doesn't give me a good distribution.

```
seq(from = 1e-321, to = 1e-200, by = ((1e-200 - 1e-321)/624))
```

gives an output like this where only one value has -322 power (which is out of my range) and all others are in 1e-203, 1e-201, 1e-200 range.
[image]

I need an output, so all 625 numbers would be evenly distributed across the given range.

Comment: It sounds like *"evenly distributed"* here has an implicit "in log space". Is that what you mean?

Comment: Simplest is `seq(from = 1e-321, to = 1e-200, length.out = 625)`.

Comment: (1) can you please post your results as text (code format) rather than as an image? (2) if @merv is right then `10^(seq(-321, -200, 625))` might do what you want ...

Comment: Also, note that not all real numbers have exact representation in machine representations. `9.980126e-322` is the closest representable number to `1e-321`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds, as @merv noted, that you want your numbers to be spaced evenly in log space, eg with a similar number in each order of magnitude. Here's one way. `1e-321` is the same as `10^-321`, so we could raise 10 to a series of exponents which themselves are evenly spaced.

```
10^seq(from = -321, to = -200, length.out = 625)
```

You'll note the output has 5 or 6 values for each order of magnitude, with each value about 1.563x the prior value. `1.563^624` (b/c there are 624 changes between 625 numbers) is approx. `e+121` which is what we want -- `1e-200` is 121 orders of magnitude larger than `1e-321`.

Comment: yes, I meant evenly spaced in log space. this is perfect. thank you!